# Improving bandwidth from RDS postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, amazon-rds

When I do `$ time psql -c "select repeat('a', 123456789)" -o /dev/null -U postgres -h hostname` I reliably get about 10 seconds, making the transfer speed ~12 MB/sec. I'd like to do better.

I get the same speed when transferring a text row of the same size (don't ask), so I don't think its an issue constructing the string with `repeat`.

The client is an EC2 instance (m4.4xlarge). It and the RDS instances are in the same AWS region and in the same VPC. Using a count of 1, the time is < 0.1 sec, confirming the latency is low.

The transfer speed of the EC2 instance doesn't seem to be the limit. speedtest-cli confirms bandwidth ~1600 Mbit/sec

The test results are the same on three RDS instances of different sizes: m4.2xlarge, m6i.xlarge, and t3.medium. All of these have >1Gbps networking.

It doesn't seem to be TCP slow start - doubling the count doubles the time.

Disabling SSL via `PGSSLMODE="disable"` didn't help.

Wrapping the `psql` command in a `while true` loop, I can invoke multiple concurrent loops and they will each transfer at 12 MB/sec, suggesting it is not a limit of the client or server.

Any suggestions? Could you try on your server? Thanks!!

Versions:

```
psql (11.18 (Ubuntu 11.18-1.pgdg22.04+1), server 11.16)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` reads the entire result set into memory and then tries to format it for output.  This formatting is relatively slow.

In my hands, your command running locally (without the -h) takes 4 seconds.  Now that is a lot less than 10 seconds, but is still a lot and we are using different systems so it is not clear how comparable to expect them to be.

If I turn off most of the formatting by adding the '-A' switch to your psql command line, then it takes about 0.8 seconds which is not far off from what it takes just to construct the repeat string.